# Could not find gem 'angular-rails-templates (>= 1.0.0.beta2, ~> 1.0) ruby'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm trying to update some of my gems but I'm having trouble updated the angular-rails-templates gem. In my gemfile I have `gem 'angular-rails-templates', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.0.beta2'` copied from here https://rubygems.org/gems/angular-rails-templates/versions/1.0.0.beta2 but when I run bundle update I get an error

> Could not find gem 'angular-rails-templates (>= 1.0.0.beta2, ~> 1.0) ruby' in any of the gem sources
>   listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone wanders into this question the answer is [here](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates/issues/129#issuecomment-181904138)

> gem 'angular-rails-templates', '>= 1.0.0.beta2'